# VueJS best way to append data to a <pre />

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I have an electron app that runs a program and captures stdout when data arrives.

I'm trying to display the contents of this output in an html pre element.

I can create a variable, and keep appending the output data as I receive it to accomplish this.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this with VueJS?  Instead of building a string and having Vue render the variable like:

```
<pre>
   {{ outputBuffer }}
</pre>
```

Would there be a way to just directly append the data as I receive it.  So, ideally, outputBuffer would contain the new data coming in and I could append it to the pre element, like using .innerHTML in a computed property maybe.

Comment: Make `outputBuffer` an array and keep pushing to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seams like a good usecase for the `v-text` and `v-for` directive. Make `outputBuffer` an array where you append your content too. And do something like this. Be sure to remove key and index from the parameters if you don't need them.

```
<pre>
  <template 
    class="scriptview-block-property"
    v-for="(value, key, index) in outputBuffer"
    v-text="value"
  />
</pre>
```

`v-text` is meant for text that is not a composition of multiple strings. It prevents stuff like unwanted linebreaks and also escapes the inputed variable therefore a `</div>` in your output will not break your app.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text

`v-for` loops over that array and gives you each element to render. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for